# A mathematical biology reference request

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, simulation, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Is there any mathematical articles that describe the differential equation modelling of locomotion of amoeba using pseduopodia? I am looking for physics based models of pressure difference modeling of pseudopodia outgrowth and locomotion and mechanisms of such models.

This request is to model such behavior for simulation. The closest I found is G. Oster and A. Perelson. Cell protrusions. In: Frontiers in Mathematical Biology. (ed. S. Levin Berlin:Springer-Verlag. pp. 53-78 which is very dated.

Comment: why downvote please explain?

Comment: for a helpful response at this site, you'll want to formulate a question that a mathematician can answer; if there is no "research math" angle, probably it's not very well suited here (hence the down votes)